# how to make DNS zone file

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

my domain is easydata.ir and i create a zone file for my domain but when i use command "dig" it return:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> ns1.easydata.ir
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 41395
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.easydata.ir.               IN      A

;; Query time: 136 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 22 00:17:20 EST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

so I put my config file please tell me how to set it correctly.

```
$TTL 86400;
@ IN SOA ns1.easydata.ir. root.easydata.ir. (
  2013042201 ;Serial
  3600 ;Refresh
  1800 ;Retry
  604800 ;Expire
  86400 ;Minimum TTL ) ; add nameservers
@ IN NS ns1.easydata.ir. 
@ IN NS ns2.easydata.ir. ;IN MX 10 mail.easydata.ir.
ns1 IN A 198.143.181.237
ns2 IN A 198.143.181.237
www IN A 198.143.181.237
ftp IN A 198.143.181.237
```

Hera is my /etc/named.conf file. please tell me if it is correct.

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 198.143.181.237;};
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { localhost; 87.107.219.167; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "easydata.ir" IN {
                type master;
                file "easydata.ir.zone";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
```

Comment: Is your zone being read from /etc/named.conf?   Also, not stopping your zone from working but why have you got your MX as a comment on your name server line?

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at the domain in question shows that the delegation looks as follows:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
easydata.ir.            1440    IN      NS      ns1.easydata.ir.
easydata.ir.            1440    IN      NS      ns2.easydata.ir.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.easydata.ir.        1440    IN      A       198.143.181.237
ns2.easydata.ir.        1440    IN      A       198.143.181.237
```

(Sidenote: both ns1 and ns2 apparently have the same IP, making the existence of two `NS` entries pointless as there clearly is still a single point of failure.)

However, querying `198.143.181.237` results in a response with status `REFUSED` (ie, the nameserver is configured to not allow queries for this zone, alternatively the zone does not exist at all).

```
$ dig @198.143.181.237 easydata.ir NS +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.14-RedHat-9.11.14-2.fc31 <<>> @198.143.181.237 easydata.ir NS +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 49376
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 921222c5e444e2602d3491645e282d41475c2ae33ad32e29 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;easydata.ir.                   IN      NS

;; Query time: 106 msec
;; SERVER: 198.143.181.237#53(198.143.181.237)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 22 11:08:49 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68

$
```

Check the configuration (`named.conf` or a file referenced there using [`include`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.14/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#include_statement)), particularly that the relevant [`zone`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.14/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#zone_statement_grammar) entry is in place and whether there are [`allow-*`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.14/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#access_control) directives in the `zone` or `options` sections that would disallow queries.

Particularly this line in your config looks problematic as it severely limits who is allowed to query your nameserver:

```
allow-query     { localhost; 87.107.219.167; };
```

Commenting out or removing that line entirely is probably the cleanest solution.

Comment: I agree the "issue" is in **allow-query** but I am not sure if removing would solve it (I am not sure what is default). The solution would be to set **allow-query { any;};** in **options** or in zone definition.

Comment: @KamilJ See the linked documentation regarding what the defaults for `allow-*` are (and how they interact, maybe most importantly). The issue that I see which complicates your suggestion (`allow-query {any;};`) is that having that setting *does* result in different behavior compared to the defaults and makes it easier to shoot oneself in the foot, in particular if recursion is enabled (now or later).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Let me ask one additional thing. You wrote at the end of the answer "*Commenting out or removing that line entirely is probably the cleanest solution.*" By the link you have provided in relation to **allow-query** there is "*If not specified, the default is to allow queries from all hosts.*". Could you be more specific in the "having that setting does result in different behavior compared to the defaults"? What do you think is difference between "any" and "from all hosts" ? My comment was related explicitly to **allow-query**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @KamilJ But ignoring how the `allow-*` defaults interact is not really helpful for understanding why one way may be preferred. In this case, how your suggestion effectively also changes `allow-recursion` to be wide open instead of limited to local networks unless also explicitly overridden. (As per the ARM: ***allow-recursion**
Specifies which hosts are allowed to make recursive queries through this server. If **allow-recursion** is not set then **allow-query-cache** is used if set, otherwise **allow-query** is used if set, otherwise the default (**localnets; localhost;**) is used.*)

Comment: Ok, thanks for highlighting this "chain of interact". I am usually setting exlicitly allow-query and allow-recursion directives and not expect the defaults (it is more safe from my point of view) so I have made just focus on the issue... :)

Comment: @KamilJ That is absolutely fine. The one thing I would object to in this regard is a recommedation of setting `allow-query` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the primary name server which is the authoritative source for the domain it represents and you changed named.conf to establish your domain (let's say Example.com), you need to:

- create two new files - the forward and reverse zone files, which you'll place in the /var/named directory. This location is specified by the "directory" directive in the named.conf configuration file.

**Create the forward zone file**

The forward zone file contains "A" records that pair the names of the hosts in the zone, aka domain, with their respective IP addresses. It may also contain CNAME records, which are aliases for the real hostnames in the A records, and MX records for mail servers.

You have to create a basic forward zone file, /var/named/example.com.zone, and add the following lines to it. Your zone file should look like the sample below:

```
; Authoritative data for example.com zone
;
$TTL 1D
@   IN SOA  serv.example.com   root.serv.example.com. (
                                       2020012201      ; serial
                                       1D              ; refresh
                                       1H              ; retry
                                       1W              ; expire
                                       3H )            ; minimum

$ORIGIN         example.com.
example.com.            IN      NS      serv.example.com.
epc                     IN      A       127.0.0.1
server                  IN      A       192.168.2.1
www                     IN      CNAME   server
mail                    IN      CNAME   server
test1                   IN      A       192.168.2.24
t1                      IN      CNAME   test1

; Mail server MX record
example.com.            IN      MX      10      mail.example.com.
```

The first non-comment line  is the TTL, which in this case is one day for all records (D stands for Day). The specifiers in the SOA (Start of Authority) line are just as obvious.

The NS record must have the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of the host. There must also be an A record in the file with a valid IP address for the host. for testing, you should use the localhost IP address of 127.0.0.1. Otherwise, a real IP address.

You should use today's (as in current day of doing it) date and append a counter starting at 01 for the serial number. The serial number above is the first change of 2020.01.22. The serial number is incremented whenever the zone file is changed. If there were secondary name servers that used this one for a primary, they would not be updated unless the serial number is incremented.

Now you need to add the forward zone files to named.conf

Before your DNS server will work, however, you need to create an entry in /etc/named.conf that will point to your new zone file. Add the following lines below the entry for the top-level hints zone but before the "include" lines.

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "example.com.zone";
};
```

- restart named
- make tests using the dig and nsloookup commands:

  dig test1.example.com

  dig mx example.com

  nslookup test1.example.com

  dig www.amd.com

Be aware that using the FQDN for these commands is necessary except for the nslookup command as long as the domain and search entries of Example.com are provided in the /etc/resolv.conf file. If they are not, just use the FQDNs for all testing.

After this, you should be ready to start using the root name servers, if needed.

Comment: Disregarding other details, one thing that I would really recommend adding to this proposed workflow (before restarting anything) is something like `named-checkconf -zj`. That is, having it as an integral part of the workflow to verify that the configuration and zone data is even possible to interpret before having the nameserver (try to) use it.

Comment: Agreed, that can help.

Answer (score 0):

In your dig output you see among others that the response you get is from the Google public resolvers

```
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
```

When you are testing your own name server and DNS zones you need to instruct `dig` to query your own name server and not to use the ones from `/etc/resolve.conf` with

```
dig ns1.example.com. @127.0.0.1
```

(or whatever is the IP-address of the name server you’re testing with)